# Use mlcp to load documents to custom rest endpoint

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a custom rest endpoint for ingestion of documents. I have about 100k documents to load and I want to use `mlcp` for this.

I send some **key-value** pairs to the custom endpoint as well as the file to be loaded.

Can I use `mlcp` to load the documents via the custom endpoint ? All my core code is in library functions, the custom endpoint is just a http wrapper to capture the key value pairs and the file to be uploaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, **MLCP** uses the **XCC** protocol to communicate with `MarkLogic`. It will be able to communicate through your HTTP app server in `MarkLogic 8`, but won't be able to leverage any **REST** extension or **REST configuration** you added to it.

Instead, recreate the logic in an **MLCP** transform module, and use that instead. More details can be found in the **MLCP** user guide: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_82518

Since you put most logic inside libraries, that shouldn't be too difficult..

HTH!